# Change page setup in composer window using the QGIS API

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, print-composer

Is it possible to use the QGIS API to change the orientation within page setup in the composer window.

We have a plugin that builds a map template based on user defined options. When they choose to print portrait maps page setup defaults to landscape.

I have trying adding this snippet of code to the plugin but that does not seem to do anything - perhaps it just changes the orientation of the map item?

> ```
>     # Set orientation
>     resText = self.ui.orientationComboBox.currentText()
>     if resText.startswith('Portrait'):
>         orient = 0
>     else:
>         #Landscape
>         orient = 1
>     composerView.composition().PaperOrientation(orient)
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no direct way to set the paper orientation - you need to use [QgsComposition::setPaperSize](http://qgis.org/api/classQgsComposition.html#a9ba37074414f1937a838a9005e0d87cc) and set the page width and height as desired for your page orientation.